Optimizing Azure architecture for real-time data streaming with historical data access
I'm currently working on a project hosted in Azure and would appreciate some advice on improving the existing architecture. Below, I've outlined the current setup and the challenges I'm facing, particularly with providing clients with 60 seconds of historical data upon connection. I would love to hear your thoughts on how best to address these issues.
Current architecture:
The system (Web App) receives 500 sensor values per second, which are streamed to a server via WebSocket. The server handles two primary tasks:

Data Storage: Every 10 seconds, the server saves data to Azure Blob Storage. (This interval may increase in the future. Given the 50,000 block limit in AppendBlob, this current setup allows for approximately 138.9 hours of storage, which is sufficient for now.)
Data Processing and Distribution: The server performs calculations on the incoming data and sends the results to Azure Web PubSub. This ensures that clients (up to 10) receive pre-processed data without needing to perform the calculations themselves.

Additionally, there is a background service (Azure Function) that runs every 5 minutes to perform calculations and store the results. However, this results in the same data being processed twice. Due to the way data is stored in separate JSON files, the 'receiving' server cannot directly save this processed data along with the sensor data.
Several clients connect to a 'client' server (another Web App), which in turn connects to PubSub to display both the original sensor data and the calculated results.
Task: I want to enable clients to access 60 seconds of historical data immediately upon connecting and displaying the data.
Problem: With the current architecture, there's always a gap between the saved data and the data received from PubSub. Specifically:

The gap with sensor data can be up to 10 seconds.
The gap with calculated data can be up to 5 minutes.

Potential Solutions.

Temporary Data Storage:


I’m considering making the 'receiving' server save data in a temporary database records and continuously update it. The data would be stored just long enough to cover the delay between when data is saved to storage and when it is received from PubSub.
My concern is that clients would need to read data from three different sources: storage, this temporary database, and PubSub, which complicates the setup.

I cannot wrap my mind around it. Firstly, it will make the client to read (initially) data from 3 places: storage, this 'temporary storage', and PubSub.

Smaller File Segments and Aggregation


Due to the large amount of data, it is currently saved as files with links to these files stored in an MS SQL database. The calculations are stored in separate files split into 5-minute intervals, with metadata (start time, end time, file link) in a database table.
I’m considering modifying the 'receiving' server to save calculations every 10 seconds in smaller files, adding records to the 'calculations' table. A service could then combine these smaller files into a 5-minute block and clean up the small records.
While this would address the issue of double calculation and reduce the gap to 10 seconds, the 10-second gap would still remain.


Stream with Memory


Is there a streaming solution with built-in memory that I could use to send data from the 'receiving' server, which clients could then access as needed?

Thank you for your time.
